# Iframe content freezes? after inactive

Tags: javascript, macos, iframe, safari

I´ve created a `script` that loads an iframe into the parent DOM.
Works like this:

`var myIframe = createFrame("myIframe","http://foaas.com/awesome/mrstackoverflow") // Just an example`

which basically does this

```
function createFrame(id, link, style, modal){
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.frameBorder=0;
    iframe.scrolling="no";
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", 0);
    iframe.setAttribute("allowtransparency", true);
    iframe.id=id;
    iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
    return iframe
}
```

and is added to the DOM with

```
var myScript = document.getElementById('myScript');
var parent = myScript.parentElement;
parent.insertBefore(myIframe, myScript.nextSibling);
```

All of this works...

My issue is after some time when the browser tab has become "inactive" (?)

This occurs ... 
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfBuv.png)

The screen, content inside the iframe looks like this freezed and error (with some random parts of my other tabs.) like looking.  ***Only within the iframe*** but once I do something within the DOM it refreshes as nothing happened, everything is back to normal.

So far I´ve only encountered this error on **Mac and Safari**.

Any Ideas as to what happens here, anything anything that I can look for that can cause something like this?

Where should I start look? Within the script or inside the iframe script. Both are hosted by me. Is it possible that its the `iframe.setAttribute("allowtransparency", true);`?

Answer (score 0):

Made no difference with/without `allow transparency`

Still not sure as to why this keeps happening.
Seems that the tab has to be inactive for a while for it to happen. Found a workaround for this, its **not optimal**. 
Refresh the tab/window on visibility change.

```
   (function() {
      var hidden = "hidden";

      // Standards:
      if (hidden in document)
          document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
      else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document)
          document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
      else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document)
          document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
      else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document)
          document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
      // IE 9 and lower:
      else if ("onfocusin" in document)
          document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
      // All others:
      else
          window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide
              = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

      function onchange (evt) {
          // refresh the iframe DOM or the container
      }
      if( document[hidden] !== undefined )
          onchange({type: document[hidden] ? "blur" : "focus"});
  })();
```